# Is it possible to make extensions in a non-static class?

Tags: c#

I have this problem where i need an extension method but the class i need the extension in is a public class and not a public static class so id like to know if it is possible to make extensions in a public class.

My code

```
internal T SetClient<T>(this T @class, DiscordClient Client) where T : Control
        {
            if (@class != null)
                @class.Client = Client;
            return @class;
        }
```

Comment: Extension methods have to be in **static** class and they have to be **static** methods

Comment: Suggested reading **[Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)**

Comment: *"the class i need the extension in is a public class and not a public static"* Why do you **need** the extension to be in that class? Why can't you make a separate one?

Comment: _"id like to know if it is possible"_ -- "is it possible" questions are practically always too broad. Have you _tried_ to do it? What are you actually trying to do? What does `public` have to do with it? Your question is both over-broad and unclear. An extension method is required to be in a `static` class, but it can extend _instances_ of any type you like. Please improve your question so it's clear what you want to do, what you've tried, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Answer (score 3):

> i need the extension in is a public class and not a public static class

So it's not about the class being public, it's about it being static or not. No, extension methods have to be in a static, non-generic, top-level class.

But your sample method doesn't use any instance members, so can be static, and can be in a static class. I'd rename the `Client` parameter to `client` to follow .NET naming conventions though - and I think it makes more sense for `class` to be called `control`, given the constraint. So your code would end up as:

```cs
internal static T SetClient<T>(this T control, DiscordClient client) where T : Control
{
    // Equivalent to control != null, but preferred for modern C# code.
    if (control is object)
    {
        control.Client = client;
    }
    return control;
}
```

Comment: @Xaxlii instead of saying thanks you should click the checkmark on the answer to accept it. It will keep the question from showing up on the front page every few months as a question with no accepted answer.